# SPSS- new variable based on checking many variables for many values

Tags: spss

Hi I am computing a new variable 1 and 0 if certain codes are present in any of the 30 variables DX1 TO DX30. For the I150 in the second line, it will include all I50x so values such as I5023, I509 or I5042 etc. How could I code that instead of typing each time and every line?

```
COMPUTE Var1 =ANY('I099', DX1 TO DX30) 
OR ANY('I150', DX1 TO DX30)
OR ANY('P290', DX1 TO DX30).
EXECUTE.
```

I coded it in that way and it should only include specific values of I50x such as I5023 or I501

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do repeat` to loop through all the different values you want to test for. Like this:

```
compute Var1=0.
do repeat vls='I099' 'I150' 'P290' 'othrval'.
    if ANY(vls, DX1 TO DX30) var1=1.
end repeat.
```